# Cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in ac-aux

Tags: install-from-source, configure

This is my first time trying to compile and install anything on a linux machine. I got the latest version of https://github.com/processone/exmpp via git and read the instructions which state:

> ### 2. Build and install
>
> Exmpp uses the Autotools. Therefore
>   the process is quite common:
>
> ```
> $ ./configure
> $ make
> $ sudo make install
> ```

after type `./configure` I get the error

> Cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in ac-aux

Google was of little to no help. Not sure at all what I'm supposed to do. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 152):

I got it to create the configure script using the following tools:

```
libtoolize --force
aclocal
autoheader
automake --force-missing --add-missing
autoconf
./configure
```

I don't have all the dependencies so I can't test it right now, but this is generally how you would create a configure script from an ac file.

Comment: I'm a total noob. Can you explain what it is your doing and why the instructions in the readme file don't work?

Comment: The instructions in the README were probably blindly copied from somewhere else. I have to admit that I don't understand every detail of the autoconf toolchain; it's basically a collection of macros that are generated and used to create your configure script (which, in turn, sets the stage for the compilation and installation process). I never had to fine-tune these things, so I'm not an expert, but there are some fairly extensive explanations [here](http://sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_toc.html#SEC_Contents)

Comment: I was getting undefined macro errors when executing a configure script (such as the AX_PTHREAD macro). These macros appear to be usually defined in a subfolder 'm4'. Replacing autoconf with autoreconf in sebastian_k's answer, solved this issue for me.

Comment: Note to programmers: please stop using the automake toolchain. *Please*.

Comment: @Qix, could you, please, explain us why?

Comment: @Sergei it's messy, slow, and breaks constantly. It clutters up defines and is incredibly _magic_. Its way of handling dependencies (or lack thereof) gives cryptic error messages, and the files it produces are unreadable at best and nightmarishly broken at worst.

Comment: @Qix thank you much for the explaination. Which alternative you see?

Comment: @Sergei CMake is the most viable at this point in time in my opinion. I'm sure there will be something better in the (near) future.

Comment: found this series of commands very helpful!

Comment: Saved this to ~/bin/autohell.sh for future (ab)use.

Comment: @Qix The accusation on automake toolchain (I prefer to call it GNU Build System) is plain wrong, but I agree with the suggestion of not using it. It is a good tool, but most users use it the wrong way, so they are better off without it.

Answer (score 57):

Well, I tried sebastian_k's answer and it didn't work for me (`./configure` crashed midway through with an extremely weird error).

What did, however work for me was copying the instructions used in this [build log I found](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/61040100/buildlog_ubuntu-lucid-amd64.exmpp_0.9.6-0ubuntu1ppa7_BUILDING.txt.gz)

The short version(so you don't have to wade through it yourself) is:

```
$ autoreconf -vif
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/lib/erlang/lib
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: +1. `autoreconf -i` is the correct answer (the `v` and `f` are usually optional)

Comment: +1. This is the only answer that worked for me.

Comment: @Nemo nice one. The accepted answer technically works, but yours is the simplest by far.

Answer (score 14):

This question, and most of the other answers here, arise from a misunderstanding of how projects using the [GNU Build System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Build_System) (a.k.a. Autotools) are distributed.  In fact, in the case of the [Erlang XMPP library](https://github.com/processone/exmpp) mentioned by the OP, the misunderstanding appears to be on the part of the developers.

### Obtaining the software the right way

If all you want to do is compile and install a project released with the GNU Autotools, then **you should not check it out from the source control system**.  You should instead download the **packaged source release** provided by the developer.  These normally take the form of tarballs distributed on the project's website.  For projects that are hosted entirely on GitHub, Savannah, or some similar hosting service, these tarballs will usually be found behind some link labelled "Download" or "Releases".  You untar the package and utter some variant of the standard `./configure && make && sudo make install` incantation.  That's all; you don't need to invoke any of the GNU Autotools, and don't even need to have the GNU Autotools installed on your system.

The reason that you, the user, don't need the GNU Autotools to compile an Autotools-packaged project is that the developer has *already* used the various Autotools programs to generate a "distribution tarball" that can be used to build the software on any Unix-like system.  The distribution tarball contains a highly portable `configure` script that scans the build environment, checks for dependencies, and constructs a `Makefile` customized to your system.

### So when do you need Autotools?

The only reason you should need to install and invoke the GNU Autotools yourself is if you want to do *development* work on a project built with Autotools.  And even then, you probably won't need the Autotools unless you change the project's dependencies.  In that case, you would indeed need to check out the original source, make appropriate changes to the Autotools-specific input files (`configure.ac`, `Makefile.am`, etc.), and run the Autotools on them to generate a new `configure` file.  If you want to independently publish the revised package, then you would use the Makefile generated by Autotools to generate a new distribution tarball, and then publish that tarball somewhere online.

The problem is that some developers make their source repository publically available but neglect to publish their distribution tarballs (or make it difficult to find where they are published).  For example, rather than [publishing their distribution tarballs as GitHub Releases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41360302/906070), the [Erlang XMPP library's GitHub Releases](https://github.com/processone/exmpp/releases) are tarballs of the raw source repository.  This makes it impossible to compile the project without the GNU Autotools, defeating the entire purpose of using Autotools in the first place.

### TL;DR summary

The GNU Autotools are something that *developers* use to make portable source code packages for users.  *Users* should download and compile from these source packages, not the original code from the source control system.  If the developers don't provide these source packages, then they aren't using Autotools correctly, and should be [gently slapped with a wet trout](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trout#Verb) until they see the error of their ways.

Comment: How is this long post related to the question? Did OP try to use autotools? They downloaded some soft and ran `./configure && make && sudo make install` as you suggested in the second paragraph.

Comment: It's relevant because the software downloaded by the OP did not contain a correct configure script (and the most recent version in source control, plus the released tarballs, do not contain a configure script at all).  Almost all the answers here are telling the OP to run Autotools. While this may work around the problem, it's important to understand the root cause: the developers are the ones responsible for running Autotools, and they haven't done this correctly (or at all).

Comment: This is a good answer, and although I like the phrase "gently slapped with a wet trout" it might be more appropriate to explicitly mention the the correct response is to report the bug upstream.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I take it the pun is intended. :)

Comment: @Psychonaut Do you suggest that we never use a non release version of a library? For example am I supposed to use a library that has not had a release since many years ago but has lots of useful bug fixes to the main branch? I need to know how to correctly generate the `configure` file to be able to do that. In my case the last release is not even compilable anymore by new compilers/standards.

Comment: @pooya13 Again it's about using autotools correctly. The developers of a project like exmpp that uses autotools should provide a script called bootstrap or autogen.sh that runs all of the necessary commands to regenerate the configure script and related support files. They haven't done that, but at least they say what commands to run in their README. If the developers of the software you want to use haven't provided such a script or instructions in their readme, more troutslapping is appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

Please do the following to fix this problem,

```
sudo apt-get install autogen libtool shtool
```

Then do the installation

```
sh autogen.sh --prefix=prefered_install_path
make 
make install
```

Comment: Thank you, this was solving issue for me

Answer (score 4):

I've had this problem, and found it was due to the following line in `configure.ac`:

```
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build-aux])
```

The line wasn't bad per se, however it needed to be moved closer to the top of the `configure.ac` file.

Answer (score 3):

When trying to compile GNU Octave from Mercurial repository, you may come across this problem. The fix is to run `./bootstrap` while being in the root of the source tree.

Answer (score 2):

I had slightly different error:

`configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in "." "./.." "./../.."`

It turns out configure couldn't find `build-aux/install-sh`. 
I linked it like so

`ln -s build-aux/install-sh .`

then it builds.

Hope that helps someone out there!

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install automake autoconf`

its works sucessfully

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when i tried to `./configure` a source code and got the same error as posted. Finally resolved my issues by entering the code:

```
sudo apt-get install autotools-dev
```

Comment: Error: Unable to locate package autotools.

Comment: Same here. Error: Unable to locate package autotools. Downvoted. Sorry.

Comment: I already have that package installed, whatever it is. Configure script is borked nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

After installing `autogen` package this error got resolved in `wolfSSL` build.

```
sudo apt-get install autogen libtool shtool
```