# CUnit installation problem

Tags: 16.04, compiling

I am trying to install CUnit by using following steps:

1. Downloaded CUnit package from SourceForge.
2. Uncompressed it using the command:

   ```
   tar xjf CUnit-2.1-3.tar.bz2
   ```
3. Then went into the CUnit-2.1-3 directory.

   ```
   cd CUnit-2.1.2
   ```
4. Tried running the following sequence of commands:

   ```
   mkdir -p $HOME/local  
   ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local # but this command is not working
   ```

   bash is displaying the following message:

   ```
   bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
   ```

Comment: Do you execute the `./configure` command from within the `CUnit-2.1.2` directory? Please check. If so, is there a file called `configure` in the directory? Do `ls` to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually buried in the INSTALL file it says `autoconf` creates the config file.  In the README it's more explicit:

The usual sequence of steps should succeed in building and installing CUnit:

```
aclocal
```

(if necessary)

```
autoconf
```

(if necessary)

```
automake
```

(if necessary)

```
chmod u+x configure
```

(if necessary)

```
./configure --prefix <Your choice of directory for installation>
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped: https://askubuntu.com/a/27679/940185

```
libtoolize --force
aclocal
autoheader
automake --force-missing --add-missing
autoconf
./configure
```

Also, I used `wget` with [direct download link](http://CUnit-2.1-3.tar.bz2?r=https%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fcunit%2Ffiles%2FCUnit%2F2.1-3%2FCUnit-2.1-3.tar.bz2%2Fdownload%3Fuse_mirror%3Dnetcologne%26r%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fsourceforge.net%252Fprojects%252Fcunit%252F%26use_mirror) (then renamed file so that only stuff before `?` was left).